# Subsetting table under conditions shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Hi am building an application to select a dataset given several sliders input. In order to get the multiple subset i am using a for loop that it does no work. It suppose to show me in the table all the combinations that satisfy the conditions given from the sliders but as you can eventhough i ask for brand to be under a certain value is still in the table. Please if anybody can help. The code and the requested file is below:

UI.R

```
    library(shiny)

    attributes <- unique(dataset_with_key[,2])
    len <- length(attributes)

    shinyUI (pageWithSidebar (
      headerPanel("Testing"),
      sidebarPanel(
        lapply(1:2, function(i){

          sliderInput(paste("weight",i,sep="_"), 
                      paste("Select attribute levels :", attributes[i]), 
                      min = 0,
                      max = 1, 
                      step=0.05,
                      # round=-2,
                      value = c(0,1))
        }),
        selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                    unique(dataset_with_key[,1]))
      )
      , mainPanel( 
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Restrictions", h3("Analysis"),
                   tableOutput("values2"),
                   tableOutput("values")
          ),
          tabPanel("Information",textOutput("text1"))
        )
      )
    ))

SERVER.R

library(shiny)

attributes <- unique(dataset_with_key$Attribute)
tempf <- dataset_with_key$key
shinyServer( function(input,output){


  final <- reactive(function(){
    tempf <- dataset_with_key

    for (i in 1:2){
      tempcond <- dataset_with_key[round(tempf$Primary_Weights,2) <=
                                     round( eval(parse(text = paste0(paste('input$weight', i, sep='_'),"[2]"))),2)
                                   & round(tempf$Primary_Weights,2) >=
                                     round(eval(parse(text = paste0(paste('input$weight', i, sep='_'),"[1]"))),2)
                                   & tempf$Attribute==attributes[i],]

      tempf <- dataset_with_key[dataset_with_key$key %in% tempcond$key,]

    }
    tempf
  })

  output$values <- renderTable ({
    final()

  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    paste("your command output is  ",typeof(final),"Number Of Combinations",length(unique(final()$key)))
  })
})
```

and a sample of the dataset:

```
structure(list(combination = structure(c(47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), .Label = c("Comb_1", "Comb_10", 
"Comb_100", "Comb_101", "Comb_102", "Comb_103", "Comb_104", "Comb_105", 
"Comb_106", "Comb_107", "Comb_108", "Comb_109", "Comb_11", "Comb_110", 
"Comb_111", "Comb_112", "Comb_12", "Comb_13", "Comb_14", "Comb_15", 
"Comb_16", "Comb_17", "Comb_18", "Comb_19", "Comb_2", "Comb_20", 
"Comb_21", "Comb_22", "Comb_23", "Comb_24", "Comb_25", "Comb_26", 
"Comb_27", "Comb_28", "Comb_29", "Comb_3", "Comb_30", "Comb_31", 
"Comb_32", "Comb_33", "Comb_34", "Comb_35", "Comb_36", "Comb_37", 
"Comb_38", "Comb_39", "Comb_4", "Comb_40", "Comb_41", "Comb_42", 
"Comb_43", "Comb_44", "Comb_45", "Comb_46", "Comb_47", "Comb_48", 
"Comb_49", "Comb_5", "Comb_50", "Comb_51", "Comb_52", "Comb_53", 
"Comb_54", "Comb_55", "Comb_56", "Comb_57", "Comb_58", "Comb_59", 
"Comb_6", "Comb_60", "Comb_61", "Comb_62", "Comb_63", "Comb_64", 
"Comb_65", "Comb_66", "Comb_67", "Comb_68", "Comb_69", "Comb_7", 
"Comb_70", "Comb_71", "Comb_72", "Comb_73", "Comb_74", "Comb_75", 
"Comb_76", "Comb_77", "Comb_78", "Comb_79", "Comb_8", "Comb_80", 
"Comb_81", "Comb_82", "Comb_83", "Comb_84", "Comb_85", "Comb_86", 
"Comb_87", "Comb_88", "Comb_89", "Comb_9", "Comb_90", "Comb_91", 
"Comb_92", "Comb_93", "Comb_94", "Comb_95", "Comb_96", "Comb_97", 
"Comb_98", "Comb_99"), class = "factor"), Attribute = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Brand", 
"Camera", "Colour", "Connectivity", "Display_Size", "Input_Method", 
"mg_brand", "mg_color", "mg_opersystem", "mg_price2", "Operating_System", 
"Price_Bucket"), class = "factor"), Primary_Weights = c(0.0165760131, 
0, 0, 0.4382099557, 0.0715554519, 0.4354625906, 0, 0.0135417213, 
0, 0.0412302804, 0, 0.416657648, 0.0731228557, 0.410532306, 0.0175337476, 
0.0132847392, 0.0280221081, 0.0408465955, 0, 0.5417733265, 0.0142395741, 
0.3523226007, 0.0126580754, 0.0130543718, 0.0305692407, 0.0353828109, 
0, 0.4599561851, 0.1349562691, 0, 0.0273273821, 0.1398679705, 
0.037837, 0.0304305572, 0.1696246359, 0.4688031055, 0.1442811929, 
0, 0.0237889734, 0.115486818, 0.0423853165, 0.0448927516, 0.1603618421, 
0.5177030547, 0.136576526, 0, 0.0194930818, 0.0936183616, 0.0461031421, 
0.0510339776, 0.1354718562, 0.5981180958, 0.1120119023, 0, 0.0244608866, 
0.073904943, 0.0374447237, 0.0442274822, 0.1098319663, 0.490429186, 
0.1686263243, 0, 0.0253375776, 0.1033618908, 0.0449793998, 0.1672656215, 
0, 0.5603062011, 0.1229685727, 0, 0.0209758487, 0.0972089602, 
0.0524026324, 0.1461377849, 0, 0.6166255117, 0.0392621558, 0, 
0.0243300602, 0.1207420923, 0.05097111, 0.1480690699, 0, 0.7103228618, 
0.0267168423, 0, 0.0190666225, 0.0903017086, 0.0384278705, 0.1122011799, 
0.0029629144, 0.4839247401, 0.1457474446, 0, 0.027824948, 0.1166001084, 
0.0354318356, 0.1904709234, 0.5993858379, 0.0823854869, 0), vif = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), pvalue = c(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.7), key = structure(c(209L, 209L, 209L, 214L, 214L, 
214L, 214L, 214L, 214L, 214L, 214L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 
219L, 219L, 219L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 
253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 
258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 
263L, 263L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 297L, 
297L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 302L, 302L, 302L, 302L, 
302L, 302L, 302L, 302L, 307L, 307L, 307L, 307L, 307L, 307L, 307L, 
307L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 341L, 341L, 
341L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 346L, 346L, 346L), .Label = c("Comb_10060.6", 
"Comb_10070.7", "Comb_10080.8", "Comb_10090.9", "Comb_10160.6", 
"Comb_10170.7", "Comb_10180.8", "Comb_10190.9", "Comb_10260.6", 
"Comb_10270.7", "Comb_10280.8", "Comb_10290.9", "Comb_10360.6", 
"Comb_10370.7", "Comb_10380.8", "Comb_10390.9", "Comb_10460.6", 
"Comb_10470.7", "Comb_10480.8", "Comb_10490.9", "Comb_10560.6", 
"Comb_10570.7", "Comb_10580.8", "Comb_10590.9", "Comb_1060.6", 
"Comb_10660.6", "Comb_10670.7", "Comb_10680.8", "Comb_10690.9", 
"Comb_1070.7", "Comb_10760.6", "Comb_10770.7", "Comb_10780.8", 
"Comb_10790.9", "Comb_1080.8", "Comb_10860.6", "Comb_10870.7", 
"Comb_10880.8", "Comb_10890.9", "Comb_1090.9", "Comb_10960.6", 
"Comb_10970.7", "Comb_10980.8", "Comb_10990.9", "Comb_11060.6", 
"Comb_11070.7", "Comb_11080.8", "Comb_11090.9", "Comb_11160.6", 
"Comb_11170.7", "Comb_11180.8", "Comb_11190.9", "Comb_11260.6", 
"Comb_11270.7", "Comb_11280.8", "Comb_11290.9", "Comb_1160.6", 
"Comb_1170.7", "Comb_1180.8", "Comb_1190.9", "Comb_1260.6", "Comb_1270.7", 
"Comb_1280.8", "Comb_1290.9", "Comb_1360.6", "Comb_1370.7", "Comb_1380.8", 
"Comb_1390.9", "Comb_1460.6", "Comb_1470.7", "Comb_1480.8", "Comb_1490.9", 
"Comb_1560.6", "Comb_1570.7", "Comb_1580.8", "Comb_1590.9", "Comb_160.6", 
"Comb_1660.6", "Comb_1670.7", "Comb_1680.8", "Comb_1690.9", "Comb_170.7", 
"Comb_1760.6", "Comb_1770.7", "Comb_1780.8", "Comb_1790.9", "Comb_180.8", 
"Comb_1860.6", "Comb_1870.7", "Comb_1880.8", "Comb_1890.9", "Comb_190.9", 
"Comb_1960.6", "Comb_1970.7", "Comb_1980.8", "Comb_1990.9", "Comb_2060.6", 
"Comb_2070.7", "Comb_2080.8", "Comb_2090.9", "Comb_2160.6", "Comb_2170.7", 
"Comb_2180.8", "Comb_2190.9", "Comb_2260.6", "Comb_2270.7", "Comb_2280.8", 
"Comb_2290.9", "Comb_2360.6", "Comb_2370.7", "Comb_2380.8", "Comb_2390.9", 
"Comb_2460.6", "Comb_2470.7", "Comb_2480.8", "Comb_2490.9", "Comb_2560.6", 
"Comb_2570.7", "Comb_2580.8", "Comb_2590.9", "Comb_260.6", "Comb_2660.6", 
"Comb_2670.7", "Comb_2680.8", "Comb_2690.9", "Comb_270.7", "Comb_2760.6", 
"Comb_2770.7", "Comb_2780.8", "Comb_2790.9", "Comb_280.8", "Comb_2860.6", 
"Comb_2870.7", "Comb_2880.8", "Comb_2890.9", "Comb_290.9", "Comb_2960.6", 
"Comb_2970.7", "Comb_2980.8", "Comb_2990.9", "Comb_3060.6", "Comb_3070.7", 
"Comb_3080.8", "Comb_3090.9", "Comb_3160.6", "Comb_3170.7", "Comb_3180.8", 
"Comb_3190.9", "Comb_3260.6", "Comb_3270.7", "Comb_3280.8", "Comb_3290.9", 
"Comb_3360.6", "Comb_3370.7", "Comb_3380.8", "Comb_3390.9", "Comb_3460.6", 
"Comb_3470.7", "Comb_3480.8", "Comb_3490.9", "Comb_3560.6", "Comb_3570.7", 
"Comb_3580.8", "Comb_3590.9", "Comb_360.6", "Comb_3660.6", "Comb_3670.7", 
"Comb_3680.8", "Comb_3690.9", "Comb_370.7", "Comb_3760.6", "Comb_3770.7", 
"Comb_3780.8", "Comb_3790.9", "Comb_380.8", "Comb_3860.6", "Comb_3870.7", 
"Comb_3880.8", "Comb_3890.9", "Comb_390.9", "Comb_3960.6", "Comb_3970.7", 
"Comb_3980.8", "Comb_3990.9", "Comb_4060.6", "Comb_4070.7", "Comb_4080.8", 
"Comb_4090.9", "Comb_4160.6", "Comb_4170.7", "Comb_4180.8", "Comb_4190.9", 
"Comb_4260.6", "Comb_4270.7", "Comb_4280.8", "Comb_4290.9", "Comb_4360.6", 
"Comb_4370.7", "Comb_4380.8", "Comb_4390.9", "Comb_4460.6", "Comb_4470.7", 
"Comb_4480.8", "Comb_4490.9", "Comb_4560.6", "Comb_4570.7", "Comb_4580.8", 
"Comb_4590.9", "Comb_460.6", "Comb_4660.6", "Comb_4670.7", "Comb_4680.8", 
"Comb_4690.9", "Comb_470.7", "Comb_4760.6", "Comb_4770.7", "Comb_4780.8", 
"Comb_4790.9", "Comb_480.8", "Comb_4860.6", "Comb_4870.7", "Comb_4880.8", 
"Comb_4890.9", "Comb_490.9", "Comb_4960.6", "Comb_4970.7", "Comb_4980.8", 
"Comb_4990.9", "Comb_5060.6", "Comb_5070.7", "Comb_5080.8", "Comb_5090.9", 
"Comb_5160.6", "Comb_5170.7", "Comb_5180.8", "Comb_5190.9", "Comb_5260.6", 
"Comb_5270.7", "Comb_5280.8", "Comb_5290.9", "Comb_5360.6", "Comb_5370.7", 
"Comb_5380.8", "Comb_5390.9", "Comb_5460.6", "Comb_5470.7", "Comb_5480.8", 
"Comb_5490.9", "Comb_5560.6", "Comb_5570.7", "Comb_5580.8", "Comb_5590.9", 
"Comb_560.6", "Comb_5660.6", "Comb_5670.7", "Comb_5680.8", "Comb_5690.9", 
"Comb_570.7", "Comb_5760.6", "Comb_5770.7", "Comb_5780.8", "Comb_5790.9", 
"Comb_580.8", "Comb_5860.6", "Comb_5870.7", "Comb_5880.8", "Comb_5890.9", 
"Comb_590.9", "Comb_5960.6", "Comb_5970.7", "Comb_5980.8", "Comb_5990.9", 
"Comb_6060.6", "Comb_6070.7", "Comb_6080.8", "Comb_6090.9", "Comb_6160.6", 
"Comb_6170.7", "Comb_6180.8", "Comb_6190.9", "Comb_6260.6", "Comb_6270.7", 
"Comb_6280.8", "Comb_6290.9", "Comb_6360.6", "Comb_6370.7", "Comb_6380.8", 
"Comb_6390.9", "Comb_6460.6", "Comb_6470.7", "Comb_6480.8", "Comb_6490.9", 
"Comb_6560.6", "Comb_6570.7", "Comb_6580.8", "Comb_6590.9", "Comb_660.6", 
"Comb_6660.6", "Comb_6670.7", "Comb_6680.8", "Comb_6690.9", "Comb_670.7", 
"Comb_6760.6", "Comb_6770.7", "Comb_6780.8", "Comb_6790.9", "Comb_680.8", 
"Comb_6860.6", "Comb_6870.7", "Comb_6880.8", "Comb_6890.9", "Comb_690.9", 
"Comb_6960.6", "Comb_6970.7", "Comb_6980.8", "Comb_6990.9", "Comb_7060.6", 
"Comb_7070.7", "Comb_7080.8", "Comb_7090.9", "Comb_7160.6", "Comb_7170.7", 
"Comb_7180.8", "Comb_7190.9", "Comb_7260.6", "Comb_7270.7", "Comb_7280.8", 
"Comb_7290.9", "Comb_7360.6", "Comb_7370.7", "Comb_7380.8", "Comb_7390.9", 
"Comb_7460.6", "Comb_7470.7", "Comb_7480.8", "Comb_7490.9", "Comb_7560.6", 
"Comb_7570.7", "Comb_7580.8", "Comb_7590.9", "Comb_760.6", "Comb_7660.6", 
"Comb_7670.7", "Comb_7680.8", "Comb_7690.9", "Comb_770.7", "Comb_7760.6", 
"Comb_7770.7", "Comb_7780.8", "Comb_7790.9", "Comb_780.8", "Comb_7860.6", 
"Comb_7870.7", "Comb_7880.8", "Comb_7890.9", "Comb_790.9", "Comb_7960.6", 
"Comb_7970.7", "Comb_7980.8", "Comb_7990.9", "Comb_8060.6", "Comb_8070.7", 
"Comb_8080.8", "Comb_8090.9", "Comb_8160.6", "Comb_8170.7", "Comb_8180.8", 
"Comb_8190.9", "Comb_8260.6", "Comb_8270.7", "Comb_8280.8", "Comb_8290.9", 
"Comb_8360.6", "Comb_8370.7", "Comb_8380.8", "Comb_8390.9", "Comb_8460.6", 
"Comb_8470.7", "Comb_8480.8", "Comb_8490.9", "Comb_8560.6", "Comb_8570.7", 
"Comb_8580.8", "Comb_8590.9", "Comb_860.6", "Comb_8660.6", "Comb_8670.7", 
"Comb_8680.8", "Comb_8690.9", "Comb_870.7", "Comb_8760.6", "Comb_8770.7", 
"Comb_8780.8", "Comb_8790.9", "Comb_880.8", "Comb_8860.6", "Comb_8870.7", 
"Comb_8880.8", "Comb_8890.9", "Comb_890.9", "Comb_8960.6", "Comb_8970.7", 
"Comb_8980.8", "Comb_8990.9", "Comb_9060.6", "Comb_9070.7", "Comb_9080.8", 
"Comb_9090.9", "Comb_9160.6", "Comb_9170.7", "Comb_9180.8", "Comb_9190.9", 
"Comb_9260.6", "Comb_9270.7", "Comb_9280.8", "Comb_9290.9", "Comb_9360.6", 
"Comb_9370.7", "Comb_9380.8", "Comb_9390.9", "Comb_9460.6", "Comb_9470.7", 
"Comb_9480.8", "Comb_9490.9", "Comb_9560.6", "Comb_9570.7", "Comb_9580.8", 
"Comb_9590.9", "Comb_960.6", "Comb_9660.6", "Comb_9670.7", "Comb_9680.8", 
"Comb_9690.9", "Comb_970.7", "Comb_9760.6", "Comb_9770.7", "Comb_9780.8", 
"Comb_9790.9", "Comb_980.8", "Comb_9860.6", "Comb_9870.7", "Comb_9880.8", 
"Comb_9890.9", "Comb_990.9", "Comb_9960.6", "Comb_9970.7", "Comb_9980.8", 
"Comb_9990.9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("combination", 
"Attribute", "Primary_Weights", "vif", "pvalue", "key"), row.names = 100:200, class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's usually not a good idea to use `eval`. What you were trying to accomplish with

```
eval(parse(text = paste0(paste('input$weight', i, sep='_'),"[2]")))
```

could be done with

```
text = input[[paste0("weight", i, sep='_')]][2]
```

instead. But i think your real problem is that in the loop, you do nothing to combine the results of the iteration. You completely reassign `tempf` each time.

Consider changing

```
#tempf <- dataset_with_key
tempf <- dataset_with_key[0,]
```

to create an empty data frame. Then inside your look loop, change

```
#tempf <- dataset_with_key[dataset_with_key$key %in% tempcond$key,]
tempf <- cbind(tempf, dataset_with_key[dataset_with_key$key %in% tempcond$key,])
```

Note that I don't actually run shiny myself so I wasn't able to verify this works, but i'm guessing it will at least get you a lot closer to solving the problem.

Comment: MrFlick , concering the first comment you are absolutelly right and thank you very much. But concerning the second the change is not wroking because with the cbind i will always add columns and it not updates. The point with this code is that every time checks which combinations belong in the initial dataset after selecting the ones that the slider criteria satisfy. I think my problem here has to do with the reactive and observe environment but i can not figure it out.